# Set background colour of one field in wxStatusBar?

Tags: wxwidgets

I have a wxStatusBar which makes use of four fields. Now I want to change the background of one of these four fields and leave it unchanged for the other three ones. I found a method GetField() but this seems to be a dead end as the returned wxStatusBarPane inherits from nochting that would allows setting of the background colour.

So...how can I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: ,You could try to use wxGenericStatusBar, but I doubt it will be possible even there. What is it that you want to achieve with it?

Comment: @Igor the idea is to have a status message about a error condition. To properly mark it as error, it should appear on a red background (a "normal" error message via a message box does not make sense for this specific case)

Comment: why not use something like log window as in the IDE? especially if there will be multiple errors...

Answer (score 0):

Solved: the statbar-sample shows a possible solution. One can fetch the drawign context of the status-bar and then draw within whatever is desired.